# Profile temporarily shows wrong user name when using illegal characters

Tags: bug, status-declined, profile-page

When I put some funny characters in my name and try to save it, the illegal name will still be displayed at the top of the profile.

[image]

Comment: Ban him! Ban him now!

Answer (score 5):

Yeah...we're not going to fix this.